# Video player with YouTube video link for flutter app

Tags: flutter, youtube, video-player

I have a question about Video playing. Can I use [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) (without using another package) for YouTube videos. If so, how? When I set the video URL, the console is showing me the following error :

`Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Operation Stopped, null, null)`

Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can play Youtube videos via URL with this package. Seems like you need an URL of the video file (you could notice that in the documentation, where the URL is a specific place in the server, e.g. `https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4`). Meaning, you need access to the video file and not a video URL on Youtube.